# How to mock/stub methods in Elixir library Ecto/Repo?

Tags: mocking, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, stubbing

Tell me please how to mock/stub methods of `Repo` module for my tests?

For ex.:

```
  link = Repo.get_by(Link, short_url: url)
  db_count = Repo.aggregate(Link, :count, :id)
```

I need that `Repo.aggregate` returns `10000000000` for my tests. The same with `Repo.get_by`.

How to do it?

And what is the best approach for module isolation in tests in Elixir?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example from https://github.com/gialib/ex_mock readme:

```
defmodule MyTest do
  use ExUnit.Case, async: false

  import ExMock

  test "test_name" do
    with_mock HTTPotion, [get: fn(_url) -> "<html></html>" end] do
      HTTPotion.get("http://example.com")
      # Tests that make the expected call
      assert called HTTPotion.get("http://example.com")
    end
  end
end
```